# Extracting text within em tag in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

So I am in the scrapy shell and one of the selectors I try yields this :

```
>>> response.css(".result-title a").extract()
[u'<a href="#"><em>Membership warehouse</em></a>', u'<a href="#">Publix</a>', u'<a href="#">Kroger Pharmacy</a>']
```

Now to get only the text I do this :

```
>>> response.css(".result-title a::text").extract()
[u'Publix', u'Kroger Pharmacy']
```

As is evident,this omits the first element which has an additional em tag around the text.How do I extract that as well along with the normal text so that my final output is :

```
[u'Membership warehouse', u'Publix', u'Kroger Pharmacy']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would find all the text nodes at any level inside `a` and "join" them:

```
for a in response.css(".result-title a"):
     print("".join(a.xpath(".//text()").extract()))
```

Demo:

```
$ cat index.html 
<div class="result-title">
    <a href="#"><em>Membership warehouse</em></a>
    <a href="#">Publix</a>
    <a href="#">Kroger Pharmacy</a>
</div>
$ scrapy shell index.html
In [1]: for a in response.css(".result-title a"):
    print("".join(a.xpath(".//text()").extract()))
   ...:     
Membership warehouse
Publix
Kroger Pharmacy
```